# Finding the PDF of the sum of two independent standard normal variables

Tags: probability

The question asks for the PDF of $$Y=(X_1)^2+(X_2)^2$$
Given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent standard normal variables.
I found that the pdf for $(X_i)^2$  is 
$$f_{X^2}(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-x/2} x^\frac{1}{2}$$ for $x \geq 0$.
But I'm stuck on what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question may refer to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/746548/123277). Just read the entire page. I hope this helps.
$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$